# How can i simulate drag event using mouse events(mousedown, mousemove events) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

How can i simulate drag event using mouse events(mousedown, mousemove events) in JavaScript. i want to create drag event programatically, triggering mouse events.

Comment: can you use external library? rxjs? jquery? with pure javascript it would be long and error prone.

Comment: Usually this is done by attaching a mousedown listener to an element, which then attaches a mousemove and mouseup listeners to the document. In the mousemove listener you move the "draggable", and in mouseup listener you possibly "drop" the "draggable" and remove mouseup and mousemove listeners from the document. The coordinates of the "draggable" are stored to an outer scope so that all listeners can access them.

Answer (score 0):

The DragEvent interface is a DOM event that represents a drag and drop interaction.
**This interface inherits properties from MouseEvent and Event**
(You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent)).
whereas **mouseEvents** is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved over the element that has the listener attached.
You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)

Answer (score -3):

```
// add mousedown handler    
document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMousedown);

function handleMousedown() {
  // on mousedown add listeners
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseup);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove);
}

function handleMousemove(event) {
  // let's make some magic
}

function handleMouseup() {
  // on mouseup remove listeners
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseup);
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove);
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/oboshto/5c287Lzq/2/)

Comment: This is not simulating drag event.

Comment: @ChaseChoi why not? you can implement something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/oboshto/5c287Lzq/13/ similar to drag for me. Author of this question asked about realization which use mouse events, and I showed a way to do it.

Comment: Author wants more likely `MouseEvent` which triggers mouse event without moving real cursor. Your answer just listens mouse events.